# Sentence Structures

Tags: phrases

1. Who told Thuzar **about the accident**?
2. Microscopic insects can only be seen **through a microscope**.
3. The bees stung the workman **to death**.
4. The Tun Foundation presented our school **with a generous
   donation**.
5. You must not hammer nails into the walls **without permission**.
6. The teacher showed the girls **how to cook the chicken curry**.

In these sentences, how do the phrases **in bold** work?

Comment: While deadrat has answered the question, please note that: you should only ask **one question** at once; you should say **exactly** what it is you do not understand. Stack Exchange is not a homework-answering site. You may like to consider our sister site http://ell.stackexhange.com -- although the same rules apply there too.

Comment: I would like to know what the types of the phrases are in bold word.

Answer (score 1):

We can determine how the phrases fit into the sentence structures by asking how they operate.  If a phrase supplies information about place, time, manner, mode, purpose, means, frequency, duration, degree, focus, certainty, viewpoint, or evaluation, then the phrase is operating adverbially to modify the verb or an adjective.  Sometimes the scope of the modification is hard to pin down, and we say that the adverbial action applies to an entire clause.

(2) Can you see tiny insects?  Yes, but to see them requires that your eyesight must be enhanced by the **manner** of magnification.

(3) In what **manner** did the bees sting the workman?  Fatally.

(5) Can you hammer nails into the wall?  Sure, but hammering requires the **mode** of permission.

If the phrase accompanies a transitive verb, which conveys an action to a direct object, and the phrase tells us what was conveyed to the direct object, then the phrase serves as an objective complement.  That is, the phrase *completes* the meaning of transfer of action.

(4) The Tun foundation acted upon the school (the direct object) by conveyance, and what was conveyed?  A donation (the objective complement)

(6) The teacher taught the girls (the direct object of the teaching), and what was taught?  Preparing curry (the objective complement).

Sometimes the answer depends on your interpretation.  In (1) does "about the accident" modify the telling or does it complete the action of telling?  If the former, you have an adverbial; if the latter, an objective complement.

Comment: I disagree with your analysis old bean. For example, ***with a generous donation*** is a Complement of the verb in (3). It isn't an adverbial. The same goes, it seems to me for (1). The prepositional phrase seems to be a Complement, not an adverbial. (6) seems to be a Complement too. –

Comment: @Araucaria Are we on a first-legume basis?  I don't think so.  Nevertheless, your analysis is correct, and I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Sorry for the legume, but returning to the grammar... as far as I'm aware people who use the the term *objective complement* use it to refer to a predicative complement which describes the object of a clause. So for example that would be the adjective *happy* in "Chocolate made her happy". Here the adjective happy is describing "her". This does not seem to be the case in either (4) or (5). If it weren't for the fact that (4) is a PP and (5) a clause, we would say that they were objects.

Comment: @Araucaria (4) is close to an indirect object:  Tun presented our school a donation.  I don't see a problem with calling a prepositional phrase a complement.  I don't see a clause in (5), even if you mean (6).

Comment: Yes, I meant (6), not (5)! There's no problem with a PP being a complement at all. What I was trying to get at though is exactly that (4) is similar to an indirect object, and (6) is similar to a direct object (that is if it isn't actually a direct object). But, I think, the term *objective complement* isn't used to describe such complements. Objective complements are normally predicative complements which describe the object, as in the *happy* example above.

Comment: @Araucaria I was taught that in such sentences as "They elected him President," the direct object was "him," and the objective complement was "President."  Of course, this was shortly after the glaciers had receded from the North American continent, and diagramming sentences was still thought of as witchcraft in some parts of the community.  Nomenclature may have moved on since then.  In any case, thanks for the corrections to the original.

Comment: That seems right to me. The word *president* there is a description of the object, "him". So the verb's got two complements, the DO and the predicative complement, "the president". That last one is a description of the object and is therefore an "objective complement". But "with a generous donation" doesn't seem to be a description or representation of " our school" in number (4), so that's why I was a bit confused. (I'm easily confused!)